# Determining mean and SD of a parent normal distribution from a truncated data set

Tags: normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution, extrapolation

This seems like it should be easier than it is, but I'm stuck trying to determine if a data set I have represents a truncated normal distribution.  The hypothesis I'm testing is that the data you see below is actually acting as a truncated normal distribution rather than a Poisson or geometric distribution.  By being able to calculate the parent mean and standard deviation from the truncated set, I could then go on to extrapolate how the given data set would react without the limitation at the truncation.[image: Actual Data set]

I'm trying to avoid an iterative process, but can write that code and deal with the resources if absolutely necessary.  How can I determine the parent mean and standard deviation from this truncated data set?
Please bear in mind my background is in business and finance rather than statistics, so I apologize in advance for any misuse of terms or elementary basis of understanding on some of the higher statistical concepts.

Comment: For "truncated normal distribution rather than a Poisson or geometric distribution", the first option would apply to a continuous variable allowing negative values (in the non-truncated version) vs. a discrete variable allowing only non-negative values (a count). Is the nature of the data such that both of these are sensible possibilities?